# Symfony: get() - how exactly does this work?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a line in a sample Symfony app that reads:

```
$seo = $this->get('sonata.seo.page');
```

However the `config.yml` file reads:

```
sonata_seo:
page:
    metas:
        property: ... etc ...
```

I've read http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html but I'm not clear how exactly the `get('sonata.seo.page')` works. Does it somehow equate to the key / values in the `config` file? i.e. does the underscore in `sonata_seo` get magically changed to a period?

Comment: From what I have found using symfony and reviewing its container, there is `private $underscoreMap = array('_' => '', '.' => '_', '\\' => '_');` and uses `strtr()` and changes the dots to underscores ('sonata.seo') -> ('sonata_seo') within the `get()` method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access values in config.yml direcly, like values in parameters.yml.

That file can store configuration values for bundles thought.

Read more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

What it is 'getting' in this instance, usually within a controller action, is a [Symfony Service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#accessing-other-services).

In this instance, `sonata.seo.page` is a reference to a service, setup in the `sonata-project/seo-bundle`, which returns an instance of the [SeoPage](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/master/doc/reference/usage.html) class. Normally, this information is set within your local configuration file (config.yml, or a file that it includes), but the service returns the class that allows you to change the values at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No service are (directly) defined inside config.yml. It's the bundle that define the service. With `$this->get('sonata.seo.page');` you get [those](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataSeoBundle/blob/2.x/DependencyInjection/SonataSeoExtension.php#L83).

The config.yml file it's just used to customize the bundles.

Answer (score 0):

The SeoBundle defines the semantic [configuration](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataSeoBundle/blob/2.x/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) section `sonata_seo` from `config.yml` and registers the own [Extension](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataSeoBundle/blob/2.x/DependencyInjection/SonataSeoExtension.php) of DI container.

Extension implements the `load()` method. Configuration values from `sonata_seo` are passed as its first argument. 
Method loads various resources including service definition from [`Resources/config/service.xml`](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataSeoBundle/blob/2.x/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php):

```
<parameter key="sonata.seo.page.default.class">Sonata\SeoBundle\Seo\SeoPage</parameter>
...
<service id="sonata.seo.page.default" class="%sonata.seo.page.default.class%"/>
```

Next, extension set up `sonata.seo.page` [definition](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/definitions.html) with given configuration parameters. 
This process will be invoked during the container compilation, when the service definition and its settings will be embedded in the container. Result of this process you can find in the dumped container in the cache directory.

This is a [typical scheme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html) of work for the Symfony bundles: define the configuration structure, make an extension, set up the services.